Python typing specific substring type
Is it possible to define a Type in Python that only allows strings starting (or ending) with a specific substring? Such that at runtime, it's still allow to pass any string, but a static type checker will only allow the specific substring.
Example:
special_str_type = MyType("X*")  # doesn't exist

def foo(mystr: special_str_type) -> str:
    ...

# starts with "X", passes type checking
result = foo("Xabc")

# doesn't start with "X", fails type checking
result = foo("abc")

I know I can simply check this (at runtime) using e.g. mystr.startswith("X") in this case, and potentially throw an exception if it's not the case. But I'm specifically wondering if this is possible in the typing context. Maybe somehow with the builtin typing.NewType?

Using python wrappers to do that.

This seems pretty dynamic for static type checking. There might be a way to do that, but I'm not sure.

The concept you are asking about is refinement types. You can cobble together something close to what you want with a NewType wrapper around str and a type guard that "casts" a matching string to your new type.

Such that at runtime, it's still allow to pass any string, but a static type checker will only allow the specific substring This sounds like you'd want to use regex or some other pattern matching in a type hint. It's possible to write a mypy plugin for this, but the standard typing mechanism doesn't allow it.

As mentioned in Anerdw's comment, this is "pretty dynamic" for something one could try to get from a static type checker. While it doesn't seem like a lot to check whether a string starts with "X", I struggle to see the line between this and statically checking whether an integer is even, prime, or palindromic when expressed in binary. In other words, this seems to cross from static checking of types to dynamic checking of values. Furthermore, it's a tall order to (statically) check whether something continues to satisfy a condition after any modification. For instance, does a special string stay a special string if you add another string to its right? To its left?
If you're okay with any result of manipulating a special string being marked as a plain string, then I'd suggest the following as a way of creating a type that stores the information you're after:
class XString(str):
    def __new__(cls, val: str) -> "XString":
        if not val.startswith("X"):
            raise ValueError("String does not start with X")
        return super().__new__(cls, val)


def foo(mystr: XString) -> None:
    print(mystr)


foo(XString("Xylophone"))  # This will print "Xylophone"
# For the line below, Mypy says "error: Argument 1 to "foo" has incompatible type "str"; expected "XString"  [arg-type]"
foo("Guitar")  # This will print "Guitar"
foo(XString("Guitar"))  # This will raise a ValueError

x = XString("Xylophone")
y = x + " test"
print(type(y), y)  # <class 'str'> Xylophone test
z = XString(x + " test")
print(type(z), z)  # <class '__main__.XString'> Xylophone test

With this setup, any non-conforming strings will either not type check or will cause ValueErrors (see the foo examples), and any manipulation of an XString produces a plain string unless you pass it through the XString constructor again. If you want to change this behavior a little, you could redefine XString.__add__ (this is lucky, since __add__ is called for the string on the left with the string on the right as an argument; doing this for strings that end with "X" would be trickier if not impossible, since it might require redefining __add__ for the builtin str type):
class XString(str):
    ... # __new__ definition here
    def __add__(self, other: str) -> "XString":
        return XString(super().__add__(other))

x = XString("Xylophone")
y = x + " test"
print(type(y), y)  # <class '__main__.XString'> Xylophone test
foo(y)
z = "test " + x
print(type(z), z)  # <class 'str'> test Xylophone
foo(z)  # This runs without errors like foo("Guitar"), but is flagged by Mypy

